# Flutter - How to switch between cameras while recording

Tags: android, ios, flutter, camera, recording

I am using [this camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) for recording in Flutter. Is it possible to switch cameras with this package while recording since the camera controller has to be initialised every time we switch the camera.

Answer (score 2):

edit:
This is now possible in the camera package

Theres currently a PR out for that https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/6478

Comment: but when i use the camera plugin and try to toggle while recording on Android, the video after toggling part is not correct :/

Comment: What do you mean by not correct? @AlaAmarneh

Comment: hi @AlaAmarneh i just noticed the same thing, did you later see a fix?.